# Outputs on dynamic components without view

Tags: angular, angular-dynamic-components

On an Angular 8 project i created some dynmic components without a viewref with the following code:

```
const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(HelloComponent);
const componentRef = componentFactory.create(this.injector);      
componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();    
componentRef.instance.slideContentRendered.pipe(first()).subscribe(x => {console.log('does not work', x);});
```

in the HelloComponent itself i'm waiting for some async tasks to be finished and afterwards emit slideContentRendered but i do not get into the subscribe method body.

Here you can see an example application 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-krx3y6

How can i get access to the outputs? 
If i'm trying the same with a viewref with the following code it works:

```
const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
componentRef.instance.slideContentRendered.pipe(first()).subscribe(x => {console.log('it works', x);});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a BehaviorSubject, it will emit value whenever there is a listener somewhere. Subscribing to EventEmitter only triggers when there is a direct listener present when emitting. So do the following changes:

```ts
slideContentRendered = new BehaviorSubject<string>('hey');

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log('AfterViewInitTriggered');
  this.slideContentRendered.next('teeest!')
}

trigger() {
  this.testService.renderHtmlFromPresentation().subscribe(x => console.log(x));
}
```

**[FORKED STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wxfknm?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)**